# Vapor Fluent How to add a new required field key to existing table

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

I have a deployed backend built with Vapor Fluent PostgreSQL.

Now I need to add a new required field key `new_field`  to the table with schema name `schema_name`  in the database.
I created a new migration:

```
struct AddNewFieldToSchema: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema("schema_name")
            .field("new_field", .string, .required)
            .update()
    }
    
    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema("schema_name")
            .deleteField("new_field")
            .update()
    }
}
```

But after running, it gives me error:

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: server: column "new_field" of relation "schema_name" contains null values (ATRewriteTable)
```

I am guessing it is because there are existing data created using old data model that does not have values for `new_field`, because this new migration runs fine if the database is empty.

How do I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.field` function takes a list of optional properties where you can pass a default, so for you it would be

```swift
func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
  database.schema("schema_name")
    .field("new_field", .string, .required, .sql(.default("Your default value")))
    .update()
}
```

Comment: do you know how to make required to optional?

Comment: You'll need a raw query to drop the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column

Comment: thanks for answer, I will try your suggestion.